# Make a form that has undefined number of views with same fields inside and save all the values at last

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want a suggestion. I got stuck in a flow... I am not getting any idea how to proceed further.

My question is this: I have a form where a user has to fill its details. and he can add more view to fill extra details(All view will contain same textfields and labels). At last, there is a submit button to save all the data in same order.

[image]

One flow I tried was to make a tableview for this and in cell add these textfield and label and can also create new cell when user clicks add button. But got stuck when more rows got created and I tried to submit the form .. I cant access the cells which are out of View as it is the property of TableView to reuse the cell as they go out of view.

Can anyone give me suggestions for this flow. I would be grateful.

Comment: Store the values in a separate object. You can implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` and use `didEndOnExit` or `textFieldShouldReturn` methods to grab and store its value. When submit button is tapped you will have all values in your submit object. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: if you are storing "count" for number of textfields added , then you can get all the indexPaths of table , from which you can get cell & finally you can get textfield from cell.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati you can't get reference for a cell in table view that is not visible.

Comment: Yes, we can't get cell reference which is not in the view. And I would try for making a separate object and updating it when user changes something

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom Class that contains all the info you want to have in the textfields.

```
class Entry {
    var name: String
    var mail: String

    init(name: String, mail: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.mail = mail
    }
}
```

In your TableViewController create an array of these items.

```
var entries: [Entry] = []

func addEntry() {
    entries.append(Entry(name: "defaultValue", mail: "defaultValue"))
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return entries.count 
}
```

In your cellForRowAt function you should read these entries

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(...) as! ...

cell.nameField = entries[indexPath.row].name
cell.mailField = entries[indexPath.row].mail
```

and after you edit the text you should update them.

```
entries[indexOfEditedItem].name = newName
entries[indexOfEditedItem].mail = newMail
```